# How do I prevent error PHP Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in?

Tags: php

I have the following code if the file exists copy the file but I keep getting an error log sent to my server.

```
if ( file_exists("../Secondary Images Temp/".$rand2.$secondaryimg[0]) ) {
     copy("../Secondary Images Temp/".$rand2.$secondaryimg[0],"../Secondary 
     Images/".$rand2.$secondaryimg[0]);
} else {
  echo "no secondary images";
}
```

The error log file on the server prints out the following:

> [17-Mar-2018 14:09:57 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Warning:  copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/ggekozcf/public_html/Php/post_to_database_freeads.php on line 327

The code above is what is on line 327 but I have an if statement saying if the file exists.

Comment: The warning seems quite clear. You have provided a directory as the first argument to copy(). What don't you understand about it? http://php.net/copy

Comment: How do I prevent it? I am saying "if it exists" copy. It is saying there is no content to copy but I am saying "if"

Comment: [`is_dir()`](https://php.net/is_dir) could help you.

Comment: You are checking a directory not a file. You can only use copy() with files, not directories.

Comment: @vascowhite the copy function works perfectly... I had to use is_file which I was unaware of. is_dir did't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`file_exists()`](http://www.php.net/file_exists) functions checks if the path is pointing to an existing file or directory:

> Checks whether a file or directory exists.

You have to use `is_dir()` and/or `is_file()` to check the type of the path.